# Windows Server 2012 Storage Pools and TLER/CCTL/ERC enabled drives

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, storage-spaces

How do Storage Pools manage near line hdds (no raid controller) that implement TLER/CCTL/ERC? Is it completely transparent, or does that feature need to be disabled in order for the automatic corruption repair to work properly?